# Most Relevant Results from Google Books API

Tags: json, api, google-books

If im searching a book by the name only for eg `harry potter` my request is like
`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:harry+potter&key=myKey` &
im inserting my key. But the json results i get are not at all relevant it gives me random books but i want to get the actual harry potter books written by JK Rowling. Any idea how i can get the most relevant at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of using google books API, I have used goodreads API which has the books sorted according to popularity, which solved my issue.
Just make your own developer key in goodreads then you can access the data.
Check the below link for reference
[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#search.books)

Comment: Goodreads has stopped giving out new API keys as of December 2020.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, hopefully it helps someone.

Using the quotes around the search terms works fine.

Following is an example, if we want to make a search where the search term matches the title.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:"Harry+Potter"&printType=books
```

Answer (score 0):

**OpenLibrary** offers a nice search api:

Try:

https://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=Harry+Potter&author=J.K+Rowling

You could also try to request a library catalogue.

1. Library of Congress

   https://www.loc.gov/books/?all=true&fa=contributor:rowling,+j.+k.&q=Harry+Potter

   I have no idea how to get a response in a different format than html.
2. British Library.

   http://search.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?fn=search&ct=search&initialSearch=true&mode=Basic&tab=local_tab&indx=1&dum=true&srt=rank&vid=BLBNB&frbg=&vl%28freeText0%29=Harry+Potter&scp.scps=scope%3A%28BNB%29

   There is also a possibility to [get the result as RSS](http://search.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/newRss?rssId=-1740265167&ver=2_1_4). But I have no idea, how to create the RSS link directly. The underlying library system is called `Primo`. The actual API is only available for registered users.
3. World Cat

   https://www.worldcat.org/search?qt=worldcat_org&q=harry+potter&submit=Search

   The API is only for library staff :-(
4. Other alternatives with structured data.

   German catalog of books in North Rhine Westphalia. You can specify different formats in your HTTP-Header to get results as JSON, RDF or HTML.

   http://lobid.org/resources/search?agent=Rowling%2C+J.+K.&name=Harry+Potter&language.label=Englisch

... to be continued....